# Troubleshooting Ubuntu Sounds Issues with Working Speakers

Tags: sound

I'm still very new to Ubuntu and I'd like some help troubleshooting sound problems and I don't know where to start.

Specifically, I've hooked up my speakers and can play audio through them (with Ubuntu - ie. on Youtube or wherever else) but there is a weird static sound that comes out of the speakers whenever I move my mouse and when sound is playing...it's very unpleasant.

I know my speaker hardware is ok because I use the same speakers all the time on my Windows machine. So I'm imagining either the hardware is not compatible with Ubuntu or I have to update the drivers or something.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I managed to block the static sound  by going to my sound settings and leaving that window open the entire time i'll be using my headphones or speakers.

I've searched for a permanent solution but still no answer, any way, leaving the window open is not much of a problem.